# Adding Text File to Xcode Project with CMakeList.txt

Tags: xcode, cmake

If you have an Xcode project and want to add a file (say test.txt) to the project, you simply just drag and drop the file into the Xcode project and are asked if you want to "Copy items if needed" (which in this case I would do). Then you can access the file with:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Now with a Xcode project created via CMake (via CMakeLists.txt), how do I do the same thing? That is, have the test.txt file available inside the Xcode project just as if I did with the above method. Bonus points if you can make a group (AKA folder) show up inside of the Xcode project with the file inside.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of this applies to Xcode, but when generating a Visual Studio project this is done by simply adding the file to the list of source files when you create the target. The file can then be put in a folder using the `source_group` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically add it as a Resource, but you could also just add it as a regular ol' source file:

```
# This will be our group of resource files
set(project_RESOURCE_FILES
  test.txt
)

# Set properties for this group of files
set_source_files_properties(
  ${project_RESOURCE_FILES}
  PROPERTIES
  HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE # Since it's just a text file, it doesn't need compiled
  # MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resource <- only do this if you need to copy the file!
)

# Bonus points unlocked :)
source_group(
  "Resources" FILES ${project_RESOURCE_FILES}
)

# Append your resources to the source files you declared.
list(APPEND
  project_SOURCE_FILES
  ${project_RESOURCE_FILES}
}
```